# How to copy files between pods or execute in a pod?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to execute a terminal command in a pod to get the file content. 
It works fine on local:

```
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client;
const Config = require('kubernetes-client/backends/request').config;
const Request = require('kubernetes-client/backends/request');

const config = Config.fromKubeconfig();
const client = new Client({ config: config, version: '1.13' });

const podResponse = await client.api.v1.namespaces(config.namespace).pods(<pod name>).exec.get({
        qs: {
            command: ['cat', 'README.md'],
            container: <container name>,
            stdout: true,
            stderr: true,
        },
    });

console.log(podResponse.body);
```

When I run my Node.js app on Cluster with following changes:

```
const config = Request.config.getInCluster();
const backend = new Request(config);
const client = new Client({ backend });
```

it still works fine. I can get pods/services info (Node.js app run on same cluster/namespace)..
But .exec.get doesn't work. It fails with:

```
{ Error: Unexpected server response: 401
        at ClientRequest.req.on (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:579:7)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) messages: [] }
```

Again, I don't need to pass any auth info.. It works fine to get pods/services details.
Seems the issue will be fixed in new release:
[kubernetes-client repo](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/issues/346)

So wondering if there is other way to copy a file from a pod by JavaScript, i.e. analog of:

```
kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest>
```

Comment: You can cheat and ship with a copy of `kubectl` and just shell-out from JS until the client SDK catches up. Also, ensure that the `ServiceAccount` under which the Pod is running has a `Role` that permits the [verb: `get` on resource: `pods/exec`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.15.0/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-roles.yaml#L98) otherwise a 403 may be next in your future

Comment: Thank you @OhHiMark. I would better access these files as static ones provided by express service from each pod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
    kc.loadFromDefault();
    //Copy File from Local folder to POD
    const namespaceName = "default";
    const podName = "logging-poc-standalone-app-694db6684c-6dsw4";
    const containerName = "logging-poc-standalone-app";
    const cp = new k8s.Cp(kc);
    cp.cpToPod(namespaceName, podName, containerName, "log.log", "/var/log").catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

Comment: this is a code only answer. Please consider adding an explanation about the code.